# c# Can't match Html Special characters

Tags: c#, html, mysql, regex, encode

I have to match 2 urls, the first one comes from MySQL db and the second one comes from an Html page. If I compare both as string

`var match = Regex.Match(href.Attributes["href"].Value, testString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

the `match.Success = false.` Both strings are like `this : myUrl/rollcontainer-weiß` but the match.Success is still false.

I tried to add `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to check both strings and I get : `myUrl/rollcontainer-wei&#233` for the first one and `myUrl/rollcontainer-wei&amp;&szlig;` for the second one.

How can I have a `match.Success = true` in this case ?

Comment: What about this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18331804)?

Comment: I get -1 when I use Uri.Compare

Comment: Try `var match = Regex.Match(href.Attributes["href"].Value, Regex.Escape(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(testString)), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: Your second one is doubly encoded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function, for example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool test = Test("http://myUrl.com/rollcontainer-Wei&ß", "http://myUrl.com/rollcontainer-wei&amp;&szlig;");

}

public static bool Test(string url1, string url2)
{
    Uri uri1 = new Uri(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(url1)); 
    Uri uri2 = new Uri(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(url2));

    var result = Uri.Compare(uri1, uri2,
        UriComponents.Host | UriComponents.PathAndQuery,
        UriFormat.Unescaped, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    return result == 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool! It works! I tried it but without the HtmlDecode in the Uri !

Comment: FYI There is also `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` (in `System.Net`). Available since .Net 4.0.